# Advanced layout in primefaces texteditor

Tags: primefaces, quill, rich-text-editor

We just upgraded to PrimeFaces 8 and are now looking into replacing the old `p:editor` with the new `p:textEditor`. We are using these editors to send e-mails with advanced html layouts (div with custom css, table layouts, ...). We designed them in the code editor and offer our clients a wysiwyg way to modify their e-mails in this layout and send them.

As you know, the Quill editor offers a more basic way of rich-text and all this advanced formatting is now lost. Is there a way to show and edit such advanced layouts using the Quill editor? Or what is the alternative when you want to use PrimeFaces and custom client layouts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly the better alternative if the Primefaces Extensions CKEDitor.

See: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/ckEditor/basicUsage.jsf

I prefer the Office 2013 skin shown here: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/ckEditor/customToolbar.jsf

It is a full featured WYSIWYG editor for JSF.

Comment: Due to the lack of alternatives, I'm going to follow this solution. CKEditor 4 is an LTE version with support until 2023 so I'll postpone the transition to then. I hope at that time there's a better alternative or a better support for advanced layouts in Quill :-)